# Como explicar esse laço FOR em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Alguém pode me explicar como funciona esse laço e pq a ultima classe "TG" também desaparece?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Usando a classe atributo em JavaScript

Clicando no botão esconde todos os elementos com a nome da classe "cidade".
<div style = "margin-top: 20px"></div>

<div><button onclick="esconde()">Esconde</button></div>

<h2 class="cidade">London</h2>
<p>São Paulo é a capital de São Paulo.</p>

<h2 class="cidade">Paris</h2>
<p>Paris é a capital da França.</p>

<h2 class="cidade">Tokyo</h2>
<p>São Luís é a capital do Maranhão.</p>

<h2 class="cidade">TG</h2>
<p>Tokyo é a capital do Japão.</p>

<script>
function esconde() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("cidade");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você percorre todos os elementos com a classe *cidade* e oculta eles, acontece que o `header` com texto *T2* também possui a classe *cidade*  e portanto é ocultado.

Comment: Por que você acha que o último item com a classe NÃO deveria desaparecer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bom na variável `x` você tem um valor fazendo referência as classes no html que é a classe `cidade`.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("cidade");
```

Fazendo referêcia a essas classes.

```
<h2 class="cidade">London</h2>
<h2 class="cidade">Paris</h2>
<h2 class="cidade">Tokyo</h2>
<h2 class="cidade">TG</h2>
```

Depois já dentro dos `()` no `for` você tem uma variável `i` recebendo o valor `0` essa seria a inicialização do `for`.

```
for (var i = 0;)
```

Depois você tem, a variável `i` é menor do que o `x.length` essa seria a condição.

```
for(var i= 0; i < x.length;)
```

Ou seja a variável `i` é menor do que a quantidade de classe `cidade`?. No código html dentro de todos os `h2` eles possuem as mesmas classes ou seja existem 4 classes `cidades`. Então ele faz `0` é menor do que `4` se for ele executa o trecho de código `x[i].style.display = "none";`.

```
for(var i= 0; i < x.length;) {
   x[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Antes da parte `.style.display = "none";` Nessa parte `x[i]` pode parecer confuso para você mais sempre no *JavaScript* quando você acessa mais de um elemento você sempre tem que indicar qual é o elemento. Por exemplo se neste código não existisse o `for` só para ficar mais facil para você. Se você quisesse mudar a cor do primeiro `h2` com a classe `cidade`, então você usaria `document.getElementsByClassName("cidade")[0].style.color = 'red';` o `[0]` é a primeira classe então a cor seria aplicada ao primeiro `h2` com texto *London*, se você colocasse `[1]` seria a segunda classe, se colocasse `[2]` seria a terceira e assim sucessivamente. O *JavaScript* começa a contar do 0 e não 1. Então voltando na parte `x[i]` significa nada mais, nada menos que o valor de `i` vai representar as classe `cidade`.

E depois no `i++` esse operador `++` ele é o operador de incremento ele sempre incrementa +1 na variável `i`. Você poderia usar por exemplo `i = i + 1` ou `i += 1` ou se quiser incrementar em 2 em 2 usaria assim `i += 2` e assim vai que vai.

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
```

E é isso, então resumindo a variável `i` recebe `0`. `i` é menor do que a quantidade(ou comprimento) de classes `cidade`? se for execute esse bloco de código que irar desaparecer com o primeiro elemento com a classe `cidade` e incrementa +1 na variável `i` que tem o valor `0`(Passa a ter 1). depois volta de novo no `for` a variável `i`(agora `i` tem o valor `1` do incremento) a quantidade de classes `cidade` é menor do que `i` se for execute o código que irar desaparecer com o segundo elemento com a classe `cidade` e incrementa +1 na variável `i`. E assim vai executar até chegar a um ponto que vai ser `false` que é 4 é menor do que 4?. Logicamente não, então é `false`, ae ele para o `for`.
Espero ter entendido!

Comment: Entendi sim Leandro, a sua foi a mais completa explicação que eu nem esperava receber. Você é professor rs? A minha confusão era pq eu achava que o trecho `x.lenght` estava contando os caracteres de cada elemento das classes 'cidade'.

Comment: No não sou prof ainda kk, as vezes eu dou uns perdido na programação também, é normal acontece, sucesso ae! :)

Answer (score 3):

Vc tem um botão que tem `onclick="esconde()"` ou seja, quando vc clica nele executa a função `esconde()`

A função `esconde` por sua vez tem um `getElementsByClassName`, repare que é um getElement**s** no **plural**, ou seja, pega TODOS os elementos com `calss="cidade"`, pois é `ByClassName` (poderia ser tb `getElementById`, esse é `getElement` no singular, pois IDs pressupões que são únicos, não tem mais de um, então é singular getElement), não importa se é uma tag `h2` ou `div`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então `document.getElementsByClassName("cidade");` pega qualquer elemento com a classe `cidade`

O `for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)` vai criar um loop por índice, onde vai contar a partir do elemento de índice 0 e ver quantos elementos com a classe cidade existem (x.length) e depois enquanto esse número de índice do elemento for menor que a quantidade total de elementos com a classe ele vai apagando um por um até completar todos (i++)

Comment: Talvez toda a dúvida dele venha mesmo de não saber que o primeiro índice é zero. Fechei a pergunta enquanto isso não é esclarecido.

Comment: @bfavaretto sem problemas Favaretto, se ele não disser o que ele esperava e o que aconteceu que ele não entendeu fica difícil mesmo dar uma resposta. Eu escrevi, mas vc pode ver que eu mesmo tb votei pra fechar rss :D

Comment: É, só fui ver depois de fechar que tinha sido você :)

Answer (score 0):

O `getElementsByClassName("cidade")` retorna todos os elementos que possuem a classe CSS `.cidade` que no caso são os *headers* (`h2`). Então o for atribui a propriedade `display = none` a estes elementos, fazendo que o `h2` não seja mais exibido

Answer (score 0):

Você está adicionando a *x* todos os elementos que tem a classe *"cidade"* (o *getElementsByClassName("cidade")* faz isso) e depois percorre *x* com esse for, fazendo todo o elemento que contem a classe cidade ficar oculto, pois , para cada item é atribuido o *display="none"*. O elemento *TG* desaparece porque também tem a classe cidade

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente, não é apenas o "TG" que some, mas sim todos os `<h2>` que contém `class="cidade"`. Quando o botão "Esconde" é clicado, seu script interpreta todos os elementos que contém a classe "cidade" e as armazena em um array na linha:

```
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("cidade");
```

que posteriormente é iterado no `for`. Esse `for` executa de forma que ele leia todos os elementos armazenados no array, um por um, adicionando a propriedade `style.display = "none";` neles, fazendo com que os elementos "desapareçam".